# How do I solve this logarithmic equation? solving for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I solve this logarithmic equation?
$$\log_4 x = (\log_4 x)^{1/3}$$

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you mean

$$\log_4 x = \sqrt[3]{\left(\log_4 x\right)}$$

Let $l$ denote the logarithm; then we wish to solve

$$l = \sqrt[3]{l}$$

Cubing both sides gives $$l^3 = l$$

This has several solutions, since it can be rewritten as

$$0 = l^3 - l = l(l^2 - 1) = l(l - 1)(l + 1)$$

So the choices are

- $l = 0 \implies \log_4 x = 0 \implies x = 1$
- $l = 1 \implies ?$
- $l = -1 \implies ?$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  First, define $y=\log_4(x)$.  Then your equation becomes $y=\sqrt[3]y$.  Solve that, then find $x$ for each solution $y$.